# Java EE batch jobs: can I create execution scoped CDI beans?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I have a hierarchy of beans that are currently RequestScoped.
Now I'd like to use them in a batch job too.

Can I make them job-execution scoped, so that they would be recreated for each job execution?
I couldn't find anything related in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be looking for `@Stateless`, although it's not CDI, it's EJB.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html

Comment: Thanks, it works. `@RequestScope` is active within invocations of a `@Stateless` bean's methods!